# JSF Validation Error

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I don't know how helpful my query is to understand the problem. Actually i am working on an application. The flow is i have a jsf page where two combo boxes are present. Once is select option-1 the second combo gets populated. Then we press the next button and based on second option, second jsf page is loaded. Now when i go the second page and refresh, it pushes me back to the first page and gives a validation error. I am unable to understand what's happening. Any points would be helpful. I am attaching the screen shots below.

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

[image: Page 3]

Any pointers would be helpful.
Ben

Comment: Please post the relevant JSF-code.

Comment: Hi code is too lengthy to post here. Any other alternate?

Comment: Check which control causes the validation error (check for the given ID in the generated HTML) and post the code of this control - and the code of the used validator if you have written your own. I can't help you without any code.

Comment: Can i email you the code somewhere because its not allowing me to post code in here.

Comment: Edit your post or put it somewhere online and post the link in your post. (You could just put it on pastebin for example)

Comment: Like he said, post your code or make a smaller sample that duplicates the problem. It could be anything. Here's one guess: When you click Next you are being forwarded to another page but the link on the address bar is the same as the previous page. When you hit refresh it'll try to load the link on the address bar so validation kicks in. Like I said a guess, can't be sure unless we see it.

Comment: Hi andy. Thanks for your valuable suggestion. I will try to make a small sample of the program in order to reproduce the same issue.